# How to add transition to image when changing on hover

Tags: html, css

This is the best way that I found to change images on hover with CSS, but having trouble adding a transition effect so the image doesn't change abruptly.... here's a snippet that I've been working off of:

```css
a img:last-child {
  display: none;
}

a:hover img:last-child {
  display: block;
}

a:hover img:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/imoticons/105/imoticon_15-128.png" />
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/imoticons/105/imoticon_12-128.png" />
</a>
```

Would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `display` property can't be transitioned.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#cf img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="cf">
  <img class="bottom" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/imoticons/105/imoticon_12-128.png" />
  <img class="top" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/imoticons/105/imoticon_15-128.png" />
</div>
```